# When does throwing an exception break a for loop?

Tags: c#, oop, exception

Will the for loop in `DoSomething` break if an exception is thrown before we complete the loop.

```
var test = new Test(...)

try{
      //do something in test
      test.DoSomething()
  }
  catch(myException e)
  {
     \\do something about this exception
  }



class Test
{
   public void DoSomething(...)
   {
         for(var i=0;i < 5; i++)
         {
                ...

                if(some smoke)
                  {
                      throw new myException {...}
                  }

                ...
          }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? A simple execution of your code would answer your question.

Comment: How does a loop "break"? What do you mean by _"before we reach someInt-1"_? See [for (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) for the order of execution of a `for` loop. Is your question _"Will wrapping a loop in `try-catch` make the loop continue if one iteration throws an exception"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have just tested your question by defining a loop and see if you can reach a point after your exception:

```
void Main()
{
    try{
        DoSomething();
    }
    catch{
        Console.WriteLine("Yup. Breaks");
    }
}
void DoSomething()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        if( i != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loop continues");
        }
    }
}
```

And to answer your question: no, the code breaks, because the exception itself is not handled.

If you put a try/catch block inside your loop, you can call `continue;` in your catch-block after your exception has been properly dealt with to continue the iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Breaks for

```
public void DoSth()
{
    try
    {
        for(int i = 0; i ... ; i++)
        {
            if(...)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
    catch 
    {

    }
}
```

Does not break for

```
public void DoSth()
{
    for(int i = 0; i ... ; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if(...)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

    }
}
```

because when you have an exception you jump into the catch block. and when the catch block is in the for it does not break the for.
Because in the next iteration of i your are still in the for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

From [How to: Handle Exceptions in Parrallel loops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> The Parallel.For and Parallel.ForEach overloads do not have any special mechanism to handle exceptions that might be thrown.  In this respect, they resemble regular for and foreach loops (For and For Each in Visual Basic); an unhandled exception causes the loop to terminate immediately.

By throwing a new `myException(...)` you have an unhandled exception in your loop and so your loop will break and your exception thrown up to the catch above it